# what is a good way to call AJAX api multiple times in an array?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have an array of ids, and i call api like this, i'm not sure if it's correct, what if on some id it'll fail?

```
const myFunc = async () => {
try {
      for (const todoId of todoIds) {
        await fetch(
          `https://abcd123poiuy.mockapi.io/users/${
            user!.id
          }/todos/${todoId}`,
          {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({complete: completeAll}),
          },
        );
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (clearCompletedError) {
      setError(clearCompletedError);
      setLoading(false);
    }
   }
```

should while loop or maybe recursion is good? pls help

Comment: Do you want all of them to pass or break out as soon as any one of them fails ?

Comment: as soon as any of them fail, break, but i also want to see solution in both cases of your 'or' to learn please

Comment: If you want to wait after each api call, and only make the next api call when the previous one is successful you can have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640313/new-api-call-for-each-value-in-an-array

If you want to call all the api in parallel, then make an array of promises and use Promise.all on that. 
Take a look at this https://www.codementor.io/@adititipnis/javascript-how-to-make-api-calls-for-each-value-in-an-array-and-get-an-array-of-results-v1sfcj11o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd push all the promises in an array and do `Promise.all` since you want it to fail if one fails.

```
const promises = []

for (const todoId of todoIds) {
  promises.push(fetch(`someUrlwith${todoId}`));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
// success callback
}).catch(() => {
// at least one of them failed
})
```

Another solution if you want to call them one at a time

```
function loopFetch(i) {
  if (i >= todoIds.length) return; // stop when reached end
  return fetch(`someUrl${todoIds[index]}`).then(() => {
    return loopFetch(++i);
  });
}
loopFetch(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Promise chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) is a concept that executes sequence of asynchronous tasks sequentially. The developer has control over the each Promise block and take action on next sequence of Promise execution.

### Parallel Promise - (or) - [Parallel Microtasks](https://javascript.info/microtask-queue):

With [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) and [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) you gain control over the settlement of all the triggered promise.

**Advantage:** Parallely trigger all asynchronous tasks and save time.

> **Remember :** [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will return only the first **rejection** despite there may be more than one rejection in your AJAX calls & [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) will return result of either rejected or resolved promise which ever happens sooner.

#### Realtime UseCase: (*No chaining*) using `Promise.allSettled`

In real world its prudent that all [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) calls will be fired at once and **resolved / rejected** status is know in future. In this case it makes sense to know what all `fetch` calls are passed or failed and take corrective actions to only that require status attention. ***This way save network round trips!***

#### Example below for `Promise.allSettled` & `Promise.all` to show the difference.(Read code comments)

```js
const dummy = [{ //Dummy data
  value: 1,
  delay: 100,
  reject: true, //flag to explicitly reject this data
},{
  value: 2,
  delay: 200
},
{
  value: 3,
  delay: 300,
},
{
  value: 4,
  delay: 400,
  reject:true
}];

const fakeFetch = function(req){ // Fake fetch call
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("API:", req.value);
    setTimeout(req.reject ? reject : resolve, req.delay, req.value);
  })
}

const promiserSettled = async ()=>{
  let collate = [];
  for(let req of dummy){
    collate.push(fakeFetch(req));
  }
  try{ // Promise.allSettle code block
    const everthing = await Promise.allSettled(collate).then((values)=>{
      throw values.filter((val) => val.status === "rejected");
    })
    console.log("Are we done: ", everthing);
  }catch(e){
    console.log("Promise.allSettled - Rejected Value:", e); // Logs all rejected data
  }

  try{ // Promise.all code block
    const everthing = await Promise.all(collate);
    console.log("Are we done: ", everthing); 
  }catch(e){
    console.log("Promise.all - Rejected Value:", e); // Logs only one rejected data
  }
};

promiserSettled(); // Execute main
```